# .gitignore not ignore tfvars and .terraform directory

Tags: git, terraform

It appears that my .gitignore is not correct as expected.

```
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   .gitignore
        new file:   win_2016_datacentre_vm/.terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json
        new file:   win_2016_datacentre_vm/.terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v1.16.0_x4
        new file:   win_2016_datacentre_vm/aos-1.tfvars
        new file:   win_2016_datacentre_vm/aos-1.v1/.terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json
        new file:   win_2016_datacentre_vm/aos-1.v1/.terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v1.16.0_x4
        new file:   win_2016_datacentre_vm/aos-1.v1/aos-1.plan
        new file:   win_2016_datacentre_vm/aos-1.v1/aos-1.tf
        new file:   win_2016_datacentre_vm/aos-1.v1/aos-1.tfvars
        new file:   win_2016_datacentre_vm/aos-1.v1/terraform.tfstate
        new file:   win_2016_datacentre_vm/aos-1.v1/terraform.tfstate.backup


Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .gitignore

$ cat .gitignore
# Local terraform directories
docker/*
terraform-getting-started/*
terraform-getting-started.zip
**/.terraform/**
*/**/.tfvars
*.tfstate
```

What makes me wonder is even though I have added .terraform, *.tfvars and *.tfstate why is reporting them in git status?

Also should I be committing tfstate to repository?

Your assistance will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You have staged them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand [zerkms's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093911/gitignore-not-ignore-tfvars-and-terraform-directory#comment93084516_53093911) a bit, this line:

```
Changes to be committed:
```

tells you (and us) that you've already told Git: *please include these files*.

The file name `.gitignore` is rather misleading.  It seems like it's a list of files, or patterns for file names, that Git shouldn't include, but it's not: instead, it's a list of file names that Git shouldn't *add automatically* if they're not *already there* (but they are already there), and shouldn't *suggest that you **should** add*.

#### Longer, but good to know

Git's model for this is that Git builds new commits from what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or the *cache*, depending on who / which part of Git is doing the calling.  The best short description of the index that I know if is that it's where Git builds the *next commit to make* (or in this case, the first commit to make).

When you first check out some existing commit—which you can't yet, as there aren't any, but some time in the future when you use `git checkout` or `git clone` runs `git checkout` for you—Git will fill in the index *from* that commit, and then use the index's contents, as extracted from the commit, to fill in the work-tree as well.  Now the index copy and the work-tree copy both match, and both of them match the file taken out of the commit.

When you have a work-tree full of files and have changed some of them, you run `git add` to re-copy the existing work-tree files back into the index, to make them ready for the *next* commit.  Now the index copy and the work-tree copy match again, and both are *different* from the file still in the commit.  (Or, if the file is all-new, it's now in the index when it was not before.)

When you make a *new* commit, Git freezes the copies that are in the index, and puts those into the commit.  Whatever was in the index is now in the new commit, which is now the current commit.  So now the index matches the commit, as if you'd just checked out that commit.  If you had all the index files matching all the work-tree files, all three copies of every file all match, just like when you first checked out a commit.

To *remove* a file from the index, use `git rm`: this will remove it from *both* the index *and* the work-tree.  To remove it only from the index, keeping it in the work-tree, use `git rm --cached` instead.  Be careful: if the file is in some existing commit(s), and you remove it from the index, it won't be in the *new* commit you make, but it will still be the existing commits.  Checking one of those out will—or at least can—overwrite the work-tree file you left behind on purpose with `git rm --cached`.

Comment: That's a much better wording, removed mine in favour of this answer.

Comment: @zerkms: we had a bit of a race answering :-) (I thought your comment was most likely all you were going to say)

Comment: I initially only wanted to leave a comment indeed, but then decided to have some more easy reputation points! :-D

Comment: Appreciate both of your response. If it is misleading then it is should be educated.Not fault of anyone . Now your comment:
>>, it's a list of file names that Git shouldn't add automatically if they're not already there (but they are already there), and shouldn't suggest that you should add.
You you infer that that they are already there, I do not see files/directories in git status which are in .gitignore.

Comment: `git status` compares what's in your index to what's in the current commit - or in this case, to "no files" - and tells you that each new file is a new file `to be committed`. You already added them to your index before listing them in `.gitignore`. To see what's in the index directly, use `git ls-files`, but generally that's only useful for debugging.

Comment: Thank you torek :)